# WebApi Controller is not accessible other than Value controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I have a webApi UserController and a method Register named in it. Routing is done by Route attribute. Originally it's accepts POST request, I changes it to GET just to see if its being hit. The Register method which I am interested in accessing is :

```
 [Authorize]
 [ApiController]
 [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
  [AllowAnonymous]
    //[HttpGet("register")]
    public IActionResult Register()
    {
        // map dto to entity
        UserDto userDto = null;
        var user = _mapper.Map<User>(userDto);

        try
        {
            // save 
            _userService.Create(user, userDto.Password);
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (AppException ex)
        {
            // return error message if there was an exception
            return BadRequest(new { message = ex.Message });
        }
    } 
  }
```

I tried with **[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]** and **[Route("api/[controller]")]** with request corresponding to **http://localhost:55392/api/user** and **http://localhost:55392/api/user/register** but all in vain.

The same route attributes combo work good with default webApi ValueController.

Where and what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use parameter `controller` in direct route. Try below route instead:

`[Route("api/users/{action}")]`

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to include the `Http{Verb}` on the action so that it maps to the respective HTTP Verb request for the action.

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase {
    //GET api/users/register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Register() {
        //...
    } 

    //POST api/users/register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Register([FromBody]RegisterModel model) {
        //...
    } 
}
```

Reference [Token replacement in route templates ([controller], [action], [area])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area)

Comment: [HttpPost] is included at the top of Register method.

Comment: According to your questino you stated that you were testing it by changing to GET. You also had a HttpGet commented out in the example. This answer was just to match what was presented in the original question. The same would work if you wanted to POST. just replace the necessary attribute